# Python cronjob won't run

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron

When I am SSH'd into my Ubuntu 6.4 VM and run `python nomi.py`, my script executes as it should.

I set up my crontab file as follows in order to run the script every 15 mins:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command

*/15 * * * * /usr/bin/python home/cron1admin/nomi.py
```

Is there anything wrong with how I set up the crontab file? Do I need to do anything after the crontab file is created?

The `nomi.py` file sends data to Google Analytics, and when I run the script, the data goes through.  When I attempt to let the cron job run the script, nothing happens.

---

ps aux | grep cron table

```
root      1029  0.0  0.0  19120   932 ?        Ss   Jun26   0:01 cron
root      5896  0.0  0.3  73448  3724 ?        Ss   16:41   0:00 sshd: cron1admin [priv]
1000      6084  0.0  0.1  73448  1656 ?        S    16:42   0:00 sshd: cron1admin@pts/0
root      6745  0.0  0.3  73448  3628 ?        Ss   18:07   0:00 sshd: cron1admin [priv]
1000      6926  0.0  0.1  73448  1552 ?        S    18:07   0:00 sshd: cron1admin@pts/1
1000      7065  0.0  0.0   9392   944 pts/1    S+   18:21   0:00 grep --color=auto cron
```

Comment: How can I be more clear to whoever voted to close my question?

Comment: Instead of `~/` use absolute path.. `/home/me/nomi.py`

Comment: @karthikr now using absolute path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python script is not running under cron, despite working when run manually](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6363023/608639).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112246/shell-crontab-not-working) suggests that you should use absolute paths instead of relying on `~` to expand to your home directory.

Also make sure `cron` is actually running. You can do this by grepping for the `cron` process. On Ubuntu Linux, I usually use the following command.

```
ps aux | grep cron
```

Comment: how do i ensure cron is running? i get this error when i execute `sudo cron`: `cron: can't lock /var/run/crond.pid, otherpid may be 1029: Resource temporarily unavailable`

Comment: @Barnaby, I usually do `ps aux | grep cron` and see if the `cron` process is there.

Comment: I get an output that is a pretty large table.  would nothing show if it wasn't therre?

Comment: added the table to my question

Comment: @Barnaby, There is a `cron` process in that output, so I think you're good on that count. Did you already try changing the `~` to the full path?

Comment: i changed the full path and i also noticed that i had `user/bin/python` instead of `usr/bin/python`. now do i need to wait the 15 minutes to see if it will work or should it run once automatically?

Comment: @Barnaby, If you want it to run more frequently than on the `15`, you will have to change the frequency temporarily, or google for a way to force an earlier run.

Comment: Okay i guess i was asking how to force an earlier run...will do some research, thanks!

Comment: still not running after 15 mins. anything else to try?

Comment: @Barnaby, How are you verifying whether it runs or not?

Comment: well I'm not seeing the data in real time google analytics as I do when I just run the script without cron. Is there a better way to check?

Comment: @Barnaby, If you write a timestamp to a log file every time the script starts running, and then write another timestamp every time the script finishes running, you can debug whether the problem is that the script didn't run at all or the script is trying to do something which is interacting badly with cron.

Comment: i tried `*/1 * * * * echo 'Hello'` which did not work.  so i feel like this is a cron issue, not a script issue