# Cronjob not executing python script on Google Compute Engine

Tags: python, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, cron, google-compute-engine

I am unable to run the python test script below via cron to generate a csv output.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pandas as pd
cars = {'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Ford Focus','Audi A4'],
        'Price': [22000,25000,27000,35000]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['Brand', 'Price'])
df.to_csv('dftestfile2.csv', index=False)
```

Did research on similar questions asked [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56139973/python-script-using-cron-job-not-saving-output-to-file-in-google-vm-instance), [2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/unable-to-execute-a-python-script-via-crontab-but-can-execute-it-manually-what-gives)]. I have tried these different cron commands created with `sudo crontab -e` to no success:

> ```
> * * * * * cd /home/[user] && /usr/bin/python3 test.py
>
> * * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/[user]/test.py
>
> * * * * * cd /home/[user] && /usr/bin/python3 /home/[user]/test.py
> ```

I have also

- Made my script executable with `chmod +x test.py`
- Ensured CRON is running using `sudo service cron status`
- Ensured the paths are correct `/usr/bin/python` and `/home/[user]/test.py`

[Cron job logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLc4p.png)

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Are these run from `[uesr]`'s crontab? There should be no need to `cd` then; cron jobs by definition start in the invoking user's home directory.

Comment: The logs show that your job *is* running, but that you are throwing away any diagnostic output.

Comment: If the duplicate deesn't solve your problem, at the very least it should show a more exhaustive list of things to check before asking again, and what diagnostics to include in a well-defined question.